# Find the id that has completed the maximum number of lessons

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have a request (max_cl = maximum number of lessons)

```
> select s.id, count(s.id_class) as max_cl
> from classes as s 
>     join teachers as t on s.id=t.id
>  group by s.id
>  order by max_cl desc
```

This request gives this  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3v7P.png

How can i display only one id corresponding max_cl use "having",
but not like this?

```
> select s.id, count(s.id_class) as max_cl
> from classes as s 
>     join teachers as t on s.id=t.id
>  group by s.id
>  having count(s.id_class) = 948 
>  order by max_cl desc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would

```
select * from (
 select s.id, count(s.id_class) as max_cl
 from classes as s 
     join teachers as t on s.id=t.id
  group by s.id
  order by max_cl desc
) where rownum = 1
```

work?

[EDIT] You could also try tmp table expression and a window function counting the lines:

```
with tmp as (
 select s.id, count(s.id_class) as max_cl
       , row_number() over(order by count(s.id_class) desc) as rn
 from classes as s 
     join teachers as t on s.id=t.id
  group by s.id
  order by max_cl desc
)
select id, max_cl
from tmp 
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Another, somewhat more elaborate go (edit above)

Comment: yea, it works! I was not familiar with CTE, now I think it's worth it

Comment: Nice! Could you accept my answer if it was useful to you :)?